# How I should refactor my ngFor loops inside <template>?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I haven't found any examples how I should refactor my ngFor loops. This is my loop from angular 2 beta.08

```
  <template ngFor #row [ngForOf]="filterRows">
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the API page for [NgFor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html#!#syntax):

```
<li *ngFor="let row of filterRows; let i = index">...</li> `
```

```
<li template="ngFor let row of filterRows; let i = index">...</li>`
```

```
<dl>
   <template ngFor let-row [ngForOf]="filterRows" let-i="index">
      <dt>...</dt>
      <dd>...</dd>
   </template>
</dl>`
```

Note how the last form allows for multiple elements to be repeated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`<ng-container>`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ngcontainer):

```
<dl class="summary-items">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let resource of resources">
      <ng-container *ngIf="items[resource.id]>0">
        <dt class="key"><strong>{{resource.title}}:</strong></dt>
        <dd class="value">{{items[resource.id]}}</dd>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</dl>
```

Note the use of **nested** `<ng-container>` elements; you can use them wherever fit to create new templating contexts without cluttering your HTML with gratuitous elements like `<div>`s.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand your question, but just to update the newer Angular version (the 4) has this sintax:

```
  <ion-item-group *ngFor="let data of contraCheque; index as i">
      <ion-item-divider color="light">{{ data[0].competencia }}</ion-item-divider>
  </ion-item-group>
```

I'm exemple use Ionic 2, but the most important part is this:

`*ngFor="let data of contraCheque; index as i"`